# variable sized lists and using lists as variables

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to scan a parameter space of varying numbers of parameters subject to some constraints (I am interested in any number of constraints just out of curiosity, but in reality no more than 2 constraints in the actual). So it would look something like :

```
 TestScan[c1,...,cm,{list1,....listn}]
```

Where the ci are constraints and the list_i's take the form

```
 {x_i,x_i_initial, x_i_final, x_i_increment}
```

that will be fed to a Do loop.

The problem is that I want to change the actual value of the x_i so that the c_j's (which are a function of x_i) know that x_i has changed value.

For example I might have a constraint like

```
 x^2+y^2+z^2=1,
```

I want to scan over values of y and z, solve for the corresponding values of x, then store all the possible solutions in a list. By putting the variables I want to scan over in an array it seems easier since then I can have Mathematica see the size of the array, and run the proper number of loops.

Obviously if I just put the variables in a function like

```
 TestScan[c1,...,cm,x_i,x_i_initial, x_i_final, x_i_increment,....]
```

and then I would call it like

```
      TestScan[c[x1,x2],x1,x1initial, x1final, x1increment,x2,x2initial, x2final, x2increment]
```

it works since know Mathematica knows that the argument of c is that same thing as the x1 that appears elsewhere, but I would have to change the code every time I change the number of variables in the constraints. My naive straightforward generalization of the just above does't work when I try to pass all

```
 {x_i,x_i_initial, x_i_final, x_i_increment}
```

in a list. In this case mathematica might replace the 1 element in the list with something else, but I need to be able to change the value of x_i itself.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how do you plan to link the c's with the corresponding x_i's if you don't declare them explicitly

Comment: If I call it like  TestScan[c[x1,x2],{x1,x1initial, x1final, x1increment}] they should be linked no?

Comment: It's usually better for questions like these to focus on explaining what the problem is, and not focusing on your idea how to solve it. The latter *might* help, the first will leave everyone the freedom of unbiased thinking about how to solve things. For example, your suggestion of a `Do` loop is often considered bad practice in Mathematica.

Answer (score 6):

I would start by creating a function that returns a value based on your equation, i.e. the solution of your example $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$:

```
findSolutions[y_, z_] := Module[{x},
    x /. Solve[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, x]
]
```

The output looks like this:

```
findSolutions[1, 2]
```

> ```
> {-2 I, 2 I}
> ```

Next, set up the table of $(y,z)$ values you want to feed that function, for example by generating random numbers or by using some formula:

```
sampleData = Table[{y, z}, {y, -2, 2, 1/2}, {z, -1, 1, 1/3}];
sampleData = Flatten[sampleData, 1]
```

> ```
> {{-2, -1}, {-2, -2/3}, {-2, -1/3}, ...}
> ```

The second line is necessary since `Table` creates an additional nested layer for each variable it cycles through, so that the data initiall looks like `{{{ ... }}}`. The `Flatten` gets rid of this (here) unnecessary layer.

Alright, let's apply our function to the data,

```
findSolutions @@@ sampleData
```

> ```
> {{-2 I, 2 I}, {-((I Sqrt[31])/3), (I Sqrt[31])/3}, ...}
> ```

`findSolutions @@@ sampleData` applies `findSolutions` to every sublist of `sampleData`, the result is a list of all results of the function based on the data provided. You can now do additional stuff with that, for exmple use `Union` (will sort the list as well) or `DeleteDuplicates` (won't do that) to get rid of double entries; you may also want to flatten the result, since `findSolutions` returns tuples of all possible solutions for a given $(y,z)$, etc. For example `// Flatten // Union` yields

> ```
> {-1, 0, -I/3, I/3,  ...}
> ```

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for all your time - this definitely helps a lot and puts me on a good track. In working through this, I had another question which  which I posted separately. Thanks again.